# How to slide toggle bootstrap nav tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap nav-tab` in my page to toggle data. Here I am trying to add some simple effects to my page.when I click the tab I need slide toggle the tab content from left corner to right/top to bottom.

I tried this, but it's not working. What did I do wrong? or else is there any way in angularjs to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tt").click(function() {
    $(".tab-content").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-content div {
  width: 53%;
  height: 90px;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active tt"><a data-target="#a" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li class='tt'><a data-target="#b" data-toggle="tab">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class='tt'><a data-target="#c" data-toggle="tab">Menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">text1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="b">text2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="c">text3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qEjXj/3261/

Comment: @downvoter why did you downvote my question?may I know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index of clicked `.tt` and toggle the `tab-pane` of clicked index. Here is an example in jQuery way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tt").click(function() {
    $(".tab-content").find('.tab-pane').not(':eq('+$(this).index()+')').hide('slow');
    $(".tab-content").find('.tab-pane').eq($(this).index()).toggle({ direction: "left" }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-content div {
  width: 53%;
  height: 90px;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active tt"><a data-target="#a" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li class='tt'><a data-target="#b" data-toggle="tab">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class='tt'><a data-target="#c" data-toggle="tab">Menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">text1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="b">text2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="c">text3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I get it from left corner?like elaborating the rectangle?

Comment: How can I reduce the speed?

Comment: great!!  previous tab is closing right..I dont want to show that..how can I do it

Comment: @krish cannot understand. Yes I have hided previous tab.

Answer (score 3):

Sliding effect can be achieve via `css animations`. I have created a sample fiddle for explaining the same.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEjXj/3290/)

Animation Effect :

**Bottom to top**

```
@keyframes slideInFromBottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

**Slide from Left**

```
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

-Help :)

Comment: can I get it from left corner?like elaborating the rectangle?

Comment: sorry I couldn't see any changes :-(

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_animation like this only I want from left corner..please give me some ideas